# Work on theme files on a server & browser preview before installing it

Tags: themes, customization, design

A friend of mine who has got a live Wordpress website has bought a new theme. Before he's going to install and use it, he would like to adapt the theme's styles to his current web design. I uploaded the theme files on a different server because I hoped that I can preview the pages while I work on the CSS, but that doesn't work (blank pages).

Is there any possibility to work on the theme CSS files incl. page preview without already installing the new theme?

Comment: Do you have WordPress and the theme installed on the "different server" or are you trying to treat the theme like a set of raw HTML files? The latter won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to work on WordPress code, you ***must have*** a working server with PHP properly configured, and you must install WordPress on that server. You cannot simply open the files the way you can vanilla HTML files. That won't work. The PHP will not execute, for one, and there will be no database for another. Without those, you get little to no output, and you certainly get nothing like the dynamically generated site.

Comment: Thanky you very much for the explanation, now I understand how it works. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Fist, if you turn on wp's debug mode, the "blank page" would tell us what is going on.

But I think that that you use the wrong database setting on the second server, more often then not, mysql cant be accessed outside of the web server.

A theme is not only the CSS so I do not see how what whould help you: But using Chrome dev-tools and "work-spaces" You can apply your local custom css file to any website.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I think I have to setup WP for myself and add the theme. I just first have to make sure if I can use the licence key for my test version and my friend can still use it for his live project afterwards.